# Spam (?) from dfc-org-qa

Tags: registration

On Dec 18th I've received an email that looks like a regular "welcome, new user!" emails SF sends out.

Subject: Welcome to Developer Site

Body:

> Hi ,
>
> Welcome to Developer Site! To get started, go to
>   https://dfc-org-qa.force.com/forums/login?c=(redacted)
>
> Thanks, dfc-org-qa
>
> Username: eyescream@00df000000055l4mai.(redacted)

(Note the "Hi {nobody}" and something that looks like org id in the last line)

Does anybody have any idea what the hell? DFC = Dreamforce? Developer.force.com?

https://dfc-org-qa.my.salesforce.com/ seems to be a valid SF org with custom domain.
Quick googling yields https://twitter.com/cozimek and https://twitter.com/logontokartik, not too helpful.

I've used this mailbox to create my Dev. Edition and to authenticate on [SF Answers](https://success.salesforce.com/answers) or here... Still - looks bit fishy to be a legitimate new SF anything really.

Comment: Just one? I've gotten probably a half dozen from all over the place; my work email, a couple of my personal emails, etc.

Comment: I and a few co workers all received that Monday evening as well

Comment: I've received it too. To my work email.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a legit email, but inadvertently sent out. The force.com Twitter account commented several times on Dec 17th (example: https://twitter.com/forcedotcom/statuses/413141325853114368) and appears to be about the [developer boards update](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2013/12/developer-discussion-boards-freeze.html).

Comment: It's got the name "QA", further lending credence that it was unintentional, since QA is what one does before an official release.

Comment: Thx Mike and all commenters :) I'd swear I've answered exactly 0 times in the official forums, I focus solely on SO & SFSE... Not sure I like the fact I'm being enrolled anywhere just because I happen to have a Dev Edition. (And I didn't get it on another mailbox where I have different DE). Feels like Google+ forced down the throats of Youtube users ;)

Comment: Concur. My work email is used exclusively on the AppExchange for listing our product, and has never logged into the forums that I can recall, not even by accident. I would expect my main account with some odd 800+ solutions and 4.5k responses to have gotten a sneak peek, though :p